# Como criar um trigger pra salvar updates de duas tabelas?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, phpmyadmin, trigger

Tenho duas tabelas :

- **tabela1** : com três colunas **id_produto**, **nome_produto**, **preço_produto**;
- **tabela2** : com quatro colunas **id_marca**, **id_produto**, **nome_marca**, **preço_marca**;

Criei uma nova **tabela3** : com três colunas **id_produto**, **antigo_preco_produto**, **antigo_preco_marca**

No meu aplicativo tenho um script **php** que num dado instante fara uma **UPDATE** nas tabelas **1** e **2** precisamente nas colunas **preco_produto** e **preco_marca**.

Gostaria de criar um **TRIGGER** de modo a salvar os dados modificados nas tabelas **1** e **2** na **tabelas3**:

**MINHA LOGICA :**

`CRIE UM TRIGGER 
     ANTES DE UPDATE NA TABELA 1 e 2
     GUARDE OS ANTIGOS VALORES NA TABELA3`

**PROBLEMA :**

Como declarar as duas tabelas no **trigger** ?

Comment: Nada disso seria necessário se em sua modelagem os preços fossem armazenados em tabelas filhas. `tabela1_preco` (`id_produto`, `dt_ref`, `preço`) e também para a tabela2. Ao invés do seu aplicativo alterar o valor nas tabelas 1 e 2, seria inserido um novo registro com a data de referência atual nestas novas tabelas de preços.

Comment: @ismael a sua analogia parece-me interessante, poderia se possivel dar mais detalhes ?

Comment: Percebi que você pode criar tabelas (tabela3), então você pode mudar sua abordagem de como armazenar os preços. A **tabela de preços** deverá ser **MUITOS** em relação a tabela `produto` (1..n). Na sua aplicação, onde deve-se usar/mostrar o valor (tanto para produto como para a marca), você irá pesquisar na tabela `tabela1_preco` usando o `id_produto` e a `dt_ref`. A pesquisa do preço não é difícil de se fazer (`select top 1 preco from tabela1_preco where id_produto = @id_produto and dt_ref <= @data order by dt_ref desc` [fiz em sqlserver])

Comment: @ismael **tabela de preços** nao existe, mas sim uma coluna da **tabela1** ( tabela produto)

Comment: A **tabela de preços** você vai criar. De qualquer forma, é possível fazer do jeito que já está (com as triggers) ou remodelando. Como a pergunta é sobre a trigger, vou montá-la pra você e numa outra pergunta você pode tratar como usar uma modelagem com um nível maior de normalização.

Comment: @ismael esta bem... vou aguardar !

Answer (score 2):

André, não é possível associar um procedimento trigger a mais de uma tabela. Somente a uma única tabela.

Sugiro que implemente no próprio aplicativo a atualização da tabela de histórico. Na tabela3 faltou coluna para registrar o momento em que o preço foi alterado. Se necessitar de data e hora, sugiro que utilize o tipo de dados *smalldatetime*. Se necessitar de somente a data, pode utilizar o tipo de dados *date*.

```
-- código #1
BEGIN TRANSACTION;
declare @Hoje smalldatetime;
set @Hoje= Cast(Current_timestamp as smalldatetime);

-- acrescenta valores atuais na tabela de histórico de preços
INSERT into tabela3 (id_produto, data, antigo_preco_produto, antigo_preco_marca)
  SELECT T1.id_produto, @Hoje, T1.preço_produto, T2.preço_marca
    from tabela1 as T1 
         inner join tabela2 as T2 on T1.id_produto = T2.id_produto
    where _____;

-- atualiza tabela1
UPDATE tabela1
  set preço_produto= ...
  where _____;

-- atualiza tabela2
UPDATE tabela2
  set preço_marca= ...
  where _____;

COMMIT;
```

No código acima é necessário colocar a restrição tanto na gravação de histórico quanto na atualização de preços. Utilize a mesma regra.

Observe que o código está encapsulado por um par BEGIN TRANSACTION / COMMIT. É necessário para garantir a consistência dos dados.

Answer (score 1):

Vou postar a resposta com a trigger (simplificada).

Assim como o José Diz disse, não é possível fazer simultaneamente em uma trigger o disparo por duas tabelas distintas. 
Você deve criar uma trigger em cada tabela.

### Declaração da Tabela3

```
CREATE TABLE TABELA3 (`DATA_REF` DATETIME NOT NULL, `ID_PRODUTO` INT NOT NULL, `ANTIGO_PRECO_PRODUTO` NUMERIC(15,2), `ANTIGO_PRECO_MARCA` NUMERIC(15,2))
```

O campo data é importante para ser possível uma consulta futura.

### Trigger para a Tabela1

```
DELIMITER $$

DROP TRIGGER `TABELA1_PRODUTO `$$

CREATE TRIGGER TABELA1_PRODUTO AFTER UPDATE ON TABELA1
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    IF (NEW.PRECO_PRODUTO != OLD.PRECO_PRODUTO) THEN
        INSERT INTO TABELA3
            (`DATA_REF`, `ID_PRODUTO`, `ANTIGO_PRECO_PRODUTO`)
        VALUES
            (NOW(), NEW.ID_PRODUTO, OLD.PRECO_PRODUTO);
    END IF;
END$$
DELIMITER ;
```

Para a trigger da tabela2, basta fazer as alterações: alterar o nome da tabela e nos campos relativos.

---

Editei a resposta de SQLServer para MySql (mas não pude validar).